# slim framework route middleware

Tags: php, middleware, slim

I am trying to check that a user have uploada file from a whitelisted ip.

For now I have created a custom middleware, but I have 2 problems:

- if an exception is raised (eg.: user not found) The exception isn't catched by app->error()
- if I halt() the application, an exception is raised and see my first problem
- I would like to apply this middleware to a single route, but route middleware is called BEFORE the dispatch, so I don't have access to the request and so I have no source IP to check for (and no headers to get the user)

The user authentify himself with a basic HTTP auth, here follows my middleware

```
namespace Safemail\Middleware;

use App\Validator;
use Safemail\Model;

class LocalizationLock extends \Slim\Middleware
{
  /**
   * Deny Access
   */
  public function deny()
  {
$this->app->halt(403, \App\Utilities::array2json(array('status' => 403, 'message' => 'You are not allowed to connect from your current ip')));
  }

  /**
   * Localize user, if he's in the range, return true,
   * otherwise return false
   * @param string $username
   * @param string $ip
   * @return bool
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  protected function localize($username, $ip)
  {
    if (!$username = Model\User::findByUsername($username)) {
      throw new \Exception('User not found');
    }

    // admin can upload from everywhere
    if ($username->isAdmin()) {
      return true;
    }

    $uploadRanges = $username->getUploadAllowedRanges();

    /**
     * Upload ranges can be either an array of ranges,
     * an array of ip addresses or both.
     *
     * No ranges specified, allow, do a permissive check:
     *  - '' (empty string)
     *  - null
     *  - false
     */
    if (!$uploadRanges) {
      return true;
    }

    $uploadRanges = explode('|', $uploadRanges);
    foreach ($uploadRanges as $uploadRange) {
      if (Validator::validateIpOverRange($ip, $uploadRange) ||
        (Validator::validateIpAddress($uploadRange) && $uploadRange === $ip)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Call
   * This method will check the HTTP request for source IP. If
   * the request comes from an allowed ip or range, the next middleware is called. Otherwise,
   * a 425 Forbidden response is returned to the client.
   */
  public function call()
  {
    $req = $this->app->request();
    $authUser = $req->headers('PHP_AUTH_USER');
    if ($this->localize($authUser, $req->getIp())) {
      $this->next->call();
    } else {
      $this->deny();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'd like to solve my 3 issues